# How to add a rounded cap shape to rectangle element CSS

Tags: html, css, element, shapes

I need again help about create rounded caps on my element that have a gap.

I want to do something like this :
[rectange with gap and round cap][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O781h.png

After some research and trying, I ended up doing this (e.g my code). I'm happy with it, but I'd like to create more aesthetic rounded caps like in my exemple. Can anyone help me, thank you in advance.

```css
span {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #fff;
  position:absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  padding:4px;
}
p{
  border-radius: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
   border:10px solid #000;
    background-color:white;
  position:relative;
  padding-top:15px;
 
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
    <!--///////////////////////////////// début header//////////////////////////// -->
    <div id="box">
        <p><span>Title will come here</span></p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some cricles to the ends of the lines. It may need slight adjusting.

```css
span {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
}
p {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

p::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -9.3px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

p::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -9.3px;
  left: 235px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
    <!--///////////////////////////////// début header//////////////////////////// -->
    <div id="box">
      <span id="cap"></span>
        <p><span>Title will come here</span></p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend!

It works perfectly, although I still have to study exactly the pseudo element to understand the logic behind it, but many thanks for solving this mystery :)

In the meantime, what I don't understand is what leads to put it in absolute position and use the z index?